# How to track unconsumed messages in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a producer that producing messages to particular topic:

Producer:

```
  // Produce a message to a Kafka topic
        String topic = "dev.topic.proxy";
        String key = "some-key";
        String value = "Hello, Kafka!";

        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, value);

        while (true) {
            producer.send(record);
            System.out.println("Message has been sent");
        }
```

**Consumer:**

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="readMsg">
        <description>Route to refresh the proxy routes</description>
       <from uri="appKafkaConsumer:dev.topic.proxy" />
        <log message="Received message with headers: ${headers}" loggingLevel="INFO" />
        <delay>
        <constant>5000</constant>
    </delay>
    </route>
</routes>
```

This is the consumer in camel. The groupId is auto-generated randomly when I start the application. I stopped the application, when I restarted the application many messages were lost due to assigning a new groupId. I don't want to loss messages. What is the best method to solve this?

Comment: Really feels like you need persistent groupId for your consumer.

This possibly is messing with your offset logic.

Comment: Do you need camel instead of spring-kafka?

Comment: @OneCricketeer In the current time we are on camel instead of Spring-kafka

Comment: @AayushSaini groupId can be set... https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/kafka-component.html#_configuring_component_options

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the kafka consumer configured to start consuming from the earliest offset and not the latest offset.

Note that this will lead to the consumer reprocessing messages it has already received.  In order to process messages once and only once by a specific consumer, it must keep the same consumer group id.

If you want all of the messages to be processed once and only once across all consumers, then I recommend looking at ActiveMQ or a similiar queueing solution instead of Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ash, Just a query then how companies use Kafka for their use case to ensure no messages are lost due to some failure and network issue. They use multiple pods for an application and how they can handle such failure.

Comment: You're welcome.  In order to ensure accurate consumption with Kafka (or any store-and-forward solution), the consumer can reliably store their offset.  For example, if the messages lead to database updates, the offset can be updated in a transaction together with the other updates triggered by the message.

Comment: Can you share some resources to understand the concept in better way how we can store offset in DB efficiently and can use them in multiple pods.

Comment: @Aayush Kafka stores offsets in itself, not a database. If you use _Kafka transactions_, you can also guarantee records are processed once; you don't need other technologies

Comment: Kafka can be used to store the offsets itself, which complicated the solution IMO.  Just have the consumer track its own offset reliably.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can enable automatic offset commit for the consumer, this means that the consumer will periodically commit its progress to Kafka. This ensures that even if the consumer crashes or is restarted, it can recover its position from the committed offsets and resume processing without reprocessing messages.

Comment: Automatic commits doesn't guarantee exactly once processing. You can process 10 events, then crash, then reset back to the previous offset and process them all again. Crashing stops the commits, it's not guaranteed to happen